# How can I make in_memory security.yml-provided users work properly with the login form in Symfony4.3?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

So I have this new website I just made with PHP/Symfony4 but I'm having trouble making the authentication login-form work properly with `in_memory` provided users in `security.yml` file.

The login form does not log me in.

### What I do

I'm providing login and password in the the `templates/security/login.html.twig` file HTML form. I'm providing the same one that the ones stored in `security.yml`.

### What happens

After having submitted the login form, the next page loaded is the login form *again* without any error message.

### What should happen

I'm expecting to be redirect to the `/admin` URL.

#### `config/packages/security.yml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        access_users:
            memory:
                users:
                    steve:
                        password: '$2y$13$JacnEcmt6fdm2.5mt1cKIe8h8c5nMXqxQq29J2QxiK5TDKgn0DthK'
                        roles: 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            switch_user: true
            provider: access_users
            pattern: /admin$
            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin$, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

#### `src/Controller\SecurityController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="security_login", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also digged into the `src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php` but it seems to me that this is more related to a database-stored user management.

So is this even possible to make form login and `in_memory` users work together? And how should I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you create a Guard authenticator? (steps 3 & 4) https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html that's where the "magic" happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! I did it!

For further record, here the complete configuration!

`security.yml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: 'bcrypt'
        App\Security\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    steve: { password: '$2y$13$JacnEcmt6fdm2.5mt1cKIe8h8c5nMXqxQq29J2QxiK5TDKgn0DthK', roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            provider: in_memory
            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path:   security_logout
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

`login.html.twig`

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="contact-form-error alert alert-danger mt-4" id="contactError">
        <strong>Oops !</strong> {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" id="frmSignIn" method="post" class="" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="username" class="font-weight-bold text-dark text-2">Adresse email</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control form-control-lg" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="password" class="font-weight-bold text-dark text-2">Mot de passe</label>
            <input id="password" name="_password" type="password" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rememberme">
                <label class="custom-control-label text-2" for="rememberme">Se souvenir de moi</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('admin_admin_index') }}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Je m'authentifie" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern float-right" data-loading-text="Loading...">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`SecurityController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="security_login", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="security_logout", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function logout() {}
}
```

The key was in fact using properly the key `anonymous: ~`, removing the pattern, use the `access_control` and add an entry for `App\Security\User`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the login and login_check path. there are not in your firewall pattern. You should have `/admin/login`